# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). for a string comparison

Tags: python, pandas

```
for Country in energy:
    if energy[Country] == 'United States':
```

This is traversing a DataFrame in pandas called energy. energy has all the countries listed in alphabetical order with country as a column. [df energy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekcc9.png) It always gives me a ValueError if I write it out in an *if* statement but if I just do *return* it works.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-e820508b0b91> in <module>()
     20 
     21     return energy
---> 22 answer_one()

<ipython-input-61-e820508b0b91> in answer_one()
     16 
     17     for Country in energy:
---> 18         if energy[Country] == 'United States':
     19             return
     20 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
    890         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
    891                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
--> 892                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
    893 
    894     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Don't put a link to data in the question, put a sample in the question, no one want's to click a unknown external link.

Comment: can you give the whole error trace

Comment: @Ding sorry first time posting, that link goes to the image of how the DataFrame is structured.

Comment: @depperm uploaded.

Comment: When you run `for Country in energy:` you are looping through the names of the columns so that this line `if energy[Country] == 'United States':` is comparing the entire column of the data frame to  `'United States'` The return of that will be a boolean series where each item of the column is `True` or `False`.  `if` doesn't make sense in this situation because it is not a single value but rather a series of booleans it is therefore *ambiguous*

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try:

```
{
a = energy[Country] == 'United States'
   if a.any():  # if any one is Ture, return True'
   if a.all():  # if the all is Ture, return True. else,return False'
}
```

Maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `if Country == 'United States':`, not `if energy[Country] == 'United States':`. The latter compares the values in the 'United States' column to the string 'United States' (and returns a series).